# @Never transaction attribute is terribly slow

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, transactions, annotations, glassfish

I have written sort of a benchmark which estimates how different combinations of transaction attributes affect the performance  of a Java EE program. The benchmark calls a method annotated with 'Y' annotation from method with 'X' annotation. Transactions in my benchmark cover the situation of a bank transfer:

```
@Required            @RequiresNew
theCallerMethod() -> updateAccount(Account acc)
                     @RequiresNew
                  -> updateOwner(Company c)
                     @RequiresNew
                  -> addLogEntry(Transfer t)
```

So being in the context of a callerMethod transaction a container have to suspend the caller's transaction, start a new transaction, update an account, commit, switch to the caller's, suspend, start a new one, update a company, commit, return to caller's, suspend, start yet another one, add log entry, commit, and return to the caller method where finally commit the caller's transaction.

And I was quite surprised when it came out that the slowest calls was from @Never-annotated caller method: to perform 1000 described above call cases for @Required -> @Required scenario it took 5,71 sec., @Required -> @RequiresNew 6,35 sec., but **9,05** sec. for **@Never -> @Not_Supported** and **8,95** sec. for **@Never -> @Supports**.

Is it OK for @Never-contexts to execute for so long? I mean we even do not have a transaction to suspend and resume. Maybe there is some *general knowledge* about @Never transaction attribute that I have missed?

I use Java EE 6, GlassFish 3, MySQL 5.1.69 InnoDB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean we even do not have a transaction to suspend and resume.

I would not be so sure about that. This is what the ejb3.1 [specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/) says:

> 13.6.5 Handling of Methods that Run with “an unspecified transaction context”
>
> The EJB specification does not prescribe how the container should manage the execution of a method with an unspecified transaction context the transaction semantics are left to the container implementation.
> Some techniques for how the container may choose to implement the execution of a method with
> an unspecified transaction context are as follows (the list is not inclusive of all possible strategies):

(among other possibilities)

> The container may treat each call of an instance to a resource manager as a single transaction
> (e.g. the container may set the auto-commit option on a JDBC connection).